# S3 Bucket Access Denied for my HTTP client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am working on an app that is deployed to AWS EC2 (Both client and server as a separate instance).  My app uploads users' images to the s3 bucket.

I just added domains to both instances for https certification to both client and rest API

and since then I am getting this error while trying to save files to my S3 Bucket:

```
code: "AccessDenied"
extendedRequestId: "*****"
message: "Access Denied"
region: null
requestId: "****"
retryDelay: 67.72439862213535
retryable: false
statusCode: 403
time: "2020-09-12T13:42:29.739Z"
message: "Access Denied"
```

I have made this bucket public, even then it's not working.

here is my code

```
require('dotenv').config();

let multer = require('multer');
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
let { uuid } = require('uuidv4');

let s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
});
let storage = multer.memoryStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, '');
  },
});

let multiUpload = multer({ storage }).fields([
  { name: 'profile', maxCount: 1 },
  { name: 'gallery' },
]);



router.post('/', auth.required, multiUpload, async function (req, res, next) {
  var profile = new Profile();
  profile.userId = req.payload.id;

  if (typeof req.files.profile !== 'undefined') {
    let myImage = req.files.profile[0].originalname.split('.');
    let fileType = myImage[myImage.length - 1];

    let params = {
      Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: `${uuid()}.${fileType}`,
      Body: req.files.profile[0].buffer,
      ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
      ACL: 'public-read',
    };

    let data = await s3.upload(params).promise();

    if (!data.Location) res.sendStatus(500);
    profile.profileImage.url = data.Location;
    profile.profileImage.imageId = data.key;
  }
  if (typeof req.files.gallery !== 'undefined') {
    let galleryImageList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < req.files.gallery.length; i++) {
      let myImage = req.files.gallery[i].originalname.split('.');
      let fileType = myImage[myImage.length - 1];

      let params = {
        Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: `${uuid()}.${fileType}`,
        Body: req.files.gallery[i].buffer,
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
        ACL: 'public-read',
      };

      let data = await s3.upload(params).promise();
      if (!data.Location) res.sendStatus(500);
      let galleryItem = {
        url: data.Location,
        imageId: data.key,
      };

      galleryImageList.push(galleryItem);
    }
    profile.gallery = galleryImageList;
  }
 

  profile
    .save()
    .then(function () {
      return res.json({ profile: profile.toProfileJSONFor() });
    })
    .catch(next);
});
```

Comment: Do these keys have read/write access to your bucket?
`let s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
});`

Answer (score 0):

I apparently don't have enough reputation to make a comment, but you likely should include whether you're getting Access Denied from reading from the bucket or writing to the bucket or both, and you should include your code snippets that read/write from the bucket.  Also, you should include what you mean by "Added domains to both instances for https certification" because I wouldn't think that should be necessary

Editing my response since you included your code:
It looks like you are using Keys to upload your files:

```
let s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
});

let data = await s3.upload(params).promise();
```

So, if you are getting Access Denied on your writes, you should look at your keys permissions.